# Is there any purpose of using loc or iloc when filtering the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Taking into account the following:

```
df[df.B == 9]
```

vs

```
df.loc[df.B == 9]
```

I understand that 1st is syntactic sugar for the 2nd.

Generally we use loc or iloc when we need to work with label or index respectively.

However, as shown in the above examples when we are filtering the dataframe, there doesn't seen to be a use case of choosing between loc vs iloc. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes., can use that though if you wanted to mask the unselected and update.